# disable selected and other objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this door open/close script made from HTML, CSS, and JavaScript which I got from [here](https://codepen.io/adamsullovey/pen/epWzwX).

My question is how can I disable/prevent from clicking/closing again the same selected door?

For example, I will click the first door it will disable what I clicked and will also disable the remaining doors. I want this because I need to trigger an ajax request after I've clicked on one of the doors.

My javascript code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  $('#c0').clone().appendTo('.container').attr('id', 'c' + i);
}
$('.doorFrame').click(function(event){
  console.log('click');

  var doorFrame = $(event.currentTarget)
  // open door
  doorFrame.find('.swing').toggleClass('flipped');

  // ajax code here
 
});
```

Demo from [codepen](https://codepen.io/adamsullovey/pen/epWzwX):

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  $('#c0').clone().appendTo('.container').attr('id', 'c' + i);
}
$('.doorFrame').click(function(event){
  console.log('click');

  var doorFrame = $(event.currentTarget)
  // open door
  doorFrame.find('.swing').toggleClass('flipped');
  
  /*
  // move the overlay
  $('.popover').css('top', doorFrame.offset().top - 60 + "px").css('left', doorFrame.offset().left - 70 + "px").toggleClass('open');
*/
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
.container {
  background-color: tan;
  perspective: 5000px;
  margin: 100px;
}


.doorFrame {
  width: 80px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color:brown;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px 5px 2px 5px;
}

.door {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.door img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.swing {
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s, box-shadow .5s;
  transform-origin: right center; 
}

.swing figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.door .front {
  background-color:green;
  width:80px;
  height:130px;
}

.door .back {
  background-color: brown;
  width:80px;
  height:130px;
}

.swing .back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.swing:hover {
  outline:3px solid white;
}

.swing.flipped {
 transform: rotateY( 120deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}

.popover {
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#fff;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: box-shadow .5s;
  transform:scale3d(0,0,0);
}

.popover.open {
  transform:scale3d(1,1,1); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container group">
  <div class="doorFrame" id="c0">
    <div class="door swing">
      <figure class="front"><img src="http://www.sharecg.com/images/medium/11603.jpg"></figure>
      <figure class="back"><img src="http://www.sharecg.com/images/medium/11603.jpg"></figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="popover">Surprise!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated and fixed :

- In JQuery you can just use the .off() method on the main  to remove the click event. 
  Ex: `$('section.container').off("click");`
- In pure javascript (vanilla) you can just use the removeEventListener() method. 
  Ex: `document.querySelector('section.container').removeEventListener('click', function(event) {}, false);`

You can take a look at my fixed [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Natizyskunk/pen/pobPPGK).

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  $('#c0').clone().appendTo('.container').attr('id', 'c' + i);
}

$('section.container').on('click', '.doorFrame', (event) => {
  $('section.container').off("click");
  
  let doorFrame = $(event.currentTarget);
  doorFrame.find('.swing').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background-color: tan;
  perspective: 5000px;
  margin: 100px;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.doorFrame {
  width: 80px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color:brown;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px 5px 2px 5px;
}

.door {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s, box-shadow .5s;
  transform-origin: right center; 
}

.door:hover {
  outline:3px solid white;
}

.door figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.door .front {
  background-color:green;
  width:80px;
  height:130px;
}

.door .back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.door img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.door.flipped {
 transform: rotateY( 120deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container group">
  <div class="doorFrame" id="c0">
    <div class="door swing">
      <figure class="front">
        <img src="http://www.sharecg.com/images/medium/11603.jpg">
      </figure>
      <figure class="back">
        <img src="http://www.sharecg.com/images/medium/11603.jpg">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it's not flipping the door to open

Comment: My bad i've made a mistake. 
I Fixed it and now it should work the way you wanted it.
-> If you click one door, it will stay open and you can't click another one.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to just use *one*

-- edit --

Replaced .one with .on, anded a call to .off in the function handler to conform with your specifications

```
//edit - using on instead of one
$('.doorFrame').on('click',function(event){
  console.log('click');
  //edit - removing listener for all doorFrames
  $('.doorFrame').off('click', this);
  var doorFrame = $(event.currentTarget)
  // open door
  doorFrame.find('.swing').toggleClass('flipped');

  // ajax code here
 
});
```

Comment: what you mean one?

Comment: but it's not disabling the other doors, after I opened one

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: thank you, I tried your updated once again and it's still not disabling the remaining doors. and also, I can close the door, which is not gonna happen, it will remain opened